# Оптимизация возвращаемого значения в языке C

Tags: c, оптимизация, rvo

Я бы хотел узнать, что говорит `Стандарт C` об оптимизации возвращаемого значения (`RVO`).

Например:

```
typedef struct s_object
{
    // ...
} object;

object create()
{
    object o;
    o.a = ...;
    o.b = ...;
    o.c = ...;
    return o;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    object o = create();
    return 0;
}
```

В `C++` такие вещи запросто оптимизируются, и функция `create()` меняет поля сразу у того объекта, который локализуется в `main()`.

Законно ли ожидать от `C` такое же поведение?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Стандарт языка C об этом ничего не говорит, ибо стандарту языка C ничего не нужно об этом говорить.

Главным правилом оптимизации в языках C и C++ является правило "as-is": компилятор имеет право делать (оптимизировать) все, что не изменяет требуемого стандартом языка *наблюдаемого поведения* программы. Все оптимизации, которые умещаются в рамки этого правила, автоматически разрешены. Их не надо специально оговаривать в стандарте языка.

Необходимость введения и описания в стандарте языка C++ таких понятий как RVO продиктована именно тем, что применение RVO выходит за рамки правила "as-is". RVO может (и будет) приводить к изменению наблюдаемого поведения программы из-за исключения некоторых вызовов конструкторов и деструкторов. Именно для того, чтобы формально разрешить такие оптимизации стандарт языка С++ и вынужден *явно* разрешать RVO.

В языке C нет конструкторов и деструкторов. Поэтому специального разрешения на RVO в C на первый взгляд не нужно. То есть RVO была, есть и будет в языке С всегда, но явно говорить о ней в стандарте совершенно незачем. В языке С все подобные оптимизации не выходят за рамки правила "as-is".

Разглядывание сгенерированного компиляторами кода показывает, что они активно пользуются RVO в таких случаях.

---

На второй взгляд, компиляторы языка C должны учитывать, что обнаружение RVO на уровне наблюдаемого поведения может быть возможно через сравнение указателей, как в коде ниже

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct S
{
  int a[100];
};

int b;

struct S foo(struct S *p)
{
  struct S s = { rand(), rand(), rand() };
  b = &s == p;
  return s;
}

int main()
{
  struct S s = foo(&s);
  printf("%d\n", b);
}
```

Практика показывает, что GCC не выполняет в этом случае RVO, по каковой причине `b` получает значение `0`. Фактором, предотвращающим использование RVO является взятие адреса локальной переменной `s`. Это вполне логичное поведение, ибо согласно стандарту языка объекты `s` из `main` и из `foo` - это разные объекты с разными адресами.

Что интересно, Clang не отказывается от RVO и в этом случае. И Clang, начиная с версии 7, честно выполняет сравнение указателей, помещая `1` в `b`, что позволяет "обнаружить" RVO на уровне наблюдаемого поведения. Навскидку не скажу, нет ли в стандарте где-то лазейки, дозволяющей такое поведение, но скорее всего это просто баг в Clang.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за столь развернутый ответ!